# How can I play a random sound on click in a web page?

Tags: html

I want a random sound to play on a click on a button on a web page. I have researched it quite a bit and this discussion has helped me most: http://www.elated.com/forums/topic/5196/

One poster recommended making a Javascript function to run whenever the button is clicked, as follows:

```
<script>
function playSound() {
  var sounds = [
    "http://www.mysite.com/1.wav",
    "http://www.mysite.com/2.wav",
    "http://www.mysite.com/3.wav"
  ];

  **// Choose a random sound here and play it**
}
</script>
```

I understand the part about making an array of sounds. I think I have the part about selecting a random array element figured out. I am just stuck on how to play a sound inside the JS function as the poster recommends. Can I use an HTML5 audio tag inside the JS function?

I don't care whether the code for actually playing the file is inside or outside the function. Actually, I was first going to use JS just to randomly select an element, then have a line of HTML play the element of the array returned by the JS function. I gave up on that because I couldn't figure out how to specify that I wanted to play the return value of a JS function in HTML.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JavaScript to Add Sound

Place the following script in the `<head>` of your HTML document:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function playSound(soundfile) {
 document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=
 "<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
 }
 </script>
```

The Sound is Placed in an Empty Span

The JavaScript places an embed tag inside an empty span tag when the script is initiated. So, you need to add the following span file somewhere within the body of your HTML page, preferabl near the top of the document:

```
<span id="dummy"></span>
```

Call the Script with an onmouseover or onclick Attribute

The last thing you need to add is an element that you want to generate the sound on click or on mouseover. Call the script with one of those attributes:

```
<a href="#" onclick="playSound('URL to soundfile');">Click here to hear a sound</a>

 <p onmouseover="playSound('URL to soundfile');">Mouse over this text to hear a sound</p>
```

Comment: In place of 'URL to soundfile', can I put the function call? Say my function returns an element of an array of sound files. Can I then put a call of that function in place of 'URL to soundfile'? Like this:


<a href="#" onclick="playSound('randomAdLib()');">Click here to hear a sound</a>

Comment: @Coleman If you want you can keep the playSound function without any parameter and inside there put your random array of sound urls and use a random url each time the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ID of your audio element, you can do this :

```
document.getElementById(theId).play();
```

The audio element could look like this :

```
<audio id="someId">
    <source src=sound/zbluejay.wav>
</audio>
```

And if you need it, you may add the audio element dynamically like this :

```
document.write("<audio id=someId><source src=yourURL</audio>");
document.getElementById('someId').play();​​​​
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/2ZfYe/).

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested this one but I guess it should work. I basically select a random String from the array and put an embed-element into the div with the id "element" which then starts the sound.

```
<script>
function playSound() {
  var sounds = new Array(
    "http://www.mysite.com/1.wav",
    "http://www.mysite.com/2.wav",
    "http://www.mysite.com/3.wav"
  );

$.("#element").html("<embed src=\""+Math.floor(Math.random()*(sounds.length+1))+"\" autostart=\"true\" />");

}
</script>
```

**edited: i tested this one:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function playSound() {
  var sounds = new Array(
    "file:///X:/test.mp3"
  );

$("#element").html("<embed src=\""+sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*(sounds.length+1))]+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" />");
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:playSound()">

<div id="element">
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, but thanks, this is just what I was looking for, a line I could drop into my existing function. Here's all my code
`
<script>
   function randomAdLib() {
     var adLibs = [
    "C:\Users\Coleman\Documents\Web pages\Sounds\Test1.mp3",
    "C:\Users\Coleman\Documents\Web pages\Sounds\Test2.mp3",
    "C:\Users\Coleman\Documents\Web pages\Sounds\Test3.mp3"
     ];

   $.("#element").html("<embed src=\""+Math.floor(Math.random()*(adLibs.length+1))+"\" autostart=\"true\" />");
     
     
   };
  </script>
   
  <p>
  <button onclick="randomAdLib()">Try it</button>
  </p>
`

Comment: ok i updated my code. this one works! I have tested it! ... tell me if it worked for you, too :)

Comment: So the div called element is just a place to put the sound, right? Because the sound has to be somewhere in the HTML to play?