# Play random sound on image click in Wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, audio, random

Okay, so I've been researching this for a couple hours and at this point I'm probably just confusing myself more. ;)

I read the answers to this question over here: [How can I play a random sound on click in a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039984/how-can-i-play-a-random-sound-on-click-in-a-web-page/11040096#11040096)

I also read the source code earlier that that author is originally referencing.

I've added this code between the  tags in the header.php file on my Wordpress site:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function playSounds() {
  var sounds = new Array(
    "http://www.namechanged.com/laughs/laugh1.wav",
    "http://www.namechanged.com/laughs/laugh2.wav",
    "http://www.namechanged.com/laughs/laugh3.wav",
    "http://www.namechanged.com/laughs/laugh4.wav"
   );

$("#element").html("<embed src=\""+sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*(sounds.length+1))]+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" />");
}
</script>
```

and then I added this to my body tag:

```
onload="javascript:playSound()"
```

and this between my body tags:

```
<div id="element">
<button onclick="playSound()">LAUGH</button>
</div>
```

I KNOW I'm missing something painfully obvious, but I think I've been looking at this for too long to ever see what it is. Help?

Comment: I know, right? Still, challenge is a challenge!

Comment: Didn't you hear? Yahoo shut down Geocities already. It's ok, we'll get through this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be using sounds on your webpage - then I'd really recommend making use of the [Soundmanager](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) library.  It will most definitely take all of the pain out of using sound on your page.

Then adding your sound on button click would be very easy!

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:** I have fixed the function calls, and also removed the + 1 from it because it was causing that sometimes you get the index 4, which does not exist in your array and was causing the div to have a `undefined` `src` property. I also put the button outside of the div, because it was being replaced with `embed` tag. Please copy this example in your code and include the same `DOCTYPE` and see if it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function playSounds() {
            var sounds = new Array(
    "http://www.faenathara.com/laughs/Natharalaugh1.wav",
    "http://www.faenathara.com/laughs/Natharalaugh2.wav",
    "http://www.faenathara.com/laughs/Natharalaugh3.wav",
    "http://www.faenathara.com/laughs/Natharalaugh4.wav"
   );
            var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sounds.length));
            $("#element").html("<embed src=\"" + sounds[index] + "\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" />");
        }
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:playSounds()">
<button onclick="playSounds()">
            LAUGH</button>
    <div id="element">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This works totally fine for me in Chrome, Firefox and IE9.

Hanlet.

Comment: Not necessarily want to kill myself, but there was definitely a guffaw involved! Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to have been the trick. :(

Comment: Makes me wonder if maybe there's a scripting or plug in conflict that I'm missing, instead. Hmmmmm....

Comment: I am going to make a working example and post it, or maybe send it by email and see if it does not work for you. In the meantime can you tell me which browser you are using?

Comment: That's what I'm wondering, too. I've been testing it in various javascript test environments and still not getting any laughs. :( You can email me directly educatedsavage@educatedsavage.com if you like - I would appreciate it SO much. Had to take a break from this and come back. <sigh> Oh, and I'm using Chrome, but gonna go try FireFox.

Comment: The code you've entered here works for me as a standalone, but I'm having trouble integrating it into my site. I suspect because it's Wordpress and it has "<?php body_class(); ?>" in the <body> tag. So frustrating!